# Android: add dividor in menu programmatically

Tags: android, submenu

I'm trying to create a submenu where there are 3 groups of items that are added in my java code, and I want them to be separated.
This is the menu xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_filter"
    android:orderInCategory="110"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_filter"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="filter">
    <menu>
        <group android:id="@+id/no_filter"
            android:orderInCategory="101">
       </group>
        <group android:id="@+id/genre_filters"
            android:orderInCategory="102">
        </group>
        <group android:id="@+id/author_filters"
            android:orderInCategory="103">
       </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

And this is what I have in the onCreateOptionsMenu function:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_and_filter_bar, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    MenuItem filterItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter);
    SubMenu filters = filterItem.getSubMenu();
    current_filter = filters.add(R.id.no_filter,120, Menu.NONE,"All Books");
    filters.add(R.id.genre_filters,121, Menu.NONE,"Fantasy");
    filters.add(R.id.author_filters,122, Menu.NONE,"JK Rowling");
}
```

From how I understand it, there should have been a dividing line automatically between groups but there isn't. Any ideas?

By the way, when I was trying some things I added some items in the XML and they appeared above the ones I'm adding programmatically, ignoring the groups' order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would advice custom dialog, with different otions (for ex). You can create a CharSequence array with the options you want to show there and then pass the array to an AlertDialog.Builder with the method `setItems(CharSequence[], DialogInterface.OnClickListener).` Or you can use your own layout, as many examples in the web.

An example:

```
CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[] {"red", "green", "blue", "black"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // the user clicked on colors[which]
    }
});
builder.show();
```

[image]

Then you can show this menu at any position, as menu, as well.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how this relates to the problem. The menu I did does show (and the items I add too). I just want to have a separating line between the filters by genre and the filters by author